# Table in mobile always exceed the width

Tags: css, sass

i have a table data, but in mobile it's exceeding the width and scrolling the screen.

The table have a property overflow-y: auto; for the user scroll only the data views, not screen.

Follow the table CSS (SASS)

```
.table-container
    width: 100%
    overflow-y: auto
    _overflow: auto
    margin: 30px 0 50px 0
    tr
      td
        border-top: 3px solid #FFFFFF
        color: #161616
        white-space: nowrap
        font-size: 0.875rem
        &:last-child
          text-align: center
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK except the string

```
_overflow: auto
```

Delete it.

```css
.mobile {
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
}

td {
  border-top: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #161616;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Ordinary</td>
        <td>VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVery Loooong</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```